# PHP vs SQL query to split row

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I just need to point to right direction. I went a long way to make a [for most of you simple] code.

But now I am on crossroad if I should dig deeper in php or sql.

I manage to parse some web page and put the data need into sql database. The data looks like

```
<a>name of the street</a> of course I need a name of the street without html
```

now

Can I put any mysql command through php? [that means I dig deeper into sql and just pass that command]

Or does php vs mysql commands have some limitation [wich means dig deeper into regex to get better result]

Yeah I found examples how to split rows in sql I am not just sure if I can pass them.

Comment: On what criteria would you split the (sample) text in what way into ....rows?

Comment: @VolkerK well thats what I have to find out, my real output is more complex. For this one I can imagine trim 3 chars from left and 4 from right. Split was the first idea before I dig deeper and found trim option. I dont need to store the html tags of course. rows maybe I should write columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a **[three](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)** types of Database connections, or API's,  in PHP; to keep this to  the point, I am going to cover `PDO`.

> **Your question:** Can I use complex SQL in PHP, meaning put anything into the query? 
>   **The Answer:** *Yes*, you can - in fact, its just like running it inside the Database.

PHP is a **[weakly typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing)** language meaning you do not need to use *Ragex* to do complex sequences.

**An example here is joining rows for a deletion:**

```
// Connecting to the database via PDO
$dsn = 'mysql: host=localhost; dbname=example';
$user = "user";
$password = "pass";
try {
   $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
   $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

// The query
$stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE t2.* FROM table t1 JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.column= t2.column");
if($stmt->execute()): echo 'Successfully deleted!'; endif; // Conditional statements

// note this returns a bool datatype so we can check if it was successful or not
```

To learn more about PDO you can use this [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

**Note:** You may want to read up on [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) if you're taking this approach - `PDO` is secure but injections come from user-code sides. (See integration of [Classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) and [Scopes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) for security when using Databases).

**Mysqli example (as requested):**

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","name");
if($db->query("DELETE t2.* FROM table t1 JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.column= t2.column")):
    echo 'Deleted Successfully!';
endif;
```

Comment: thx a lot for a good info. I use very old book so I started with MYSQL. In meantime I tried to pass some commands and it works, so you r of course right. Thx for mentioning SQL injection, I imagine is hard to make a good code to avoid this type of vulnerability, but for testing its not the main concern right now. So after these months of php I have to go back again and learn basic sql syntax, hmm, more beyond basic I dont need simple insert or select :-). Hmm but link about sql injection look interesting a lot stuff to do :-).

Comment: `mysqli` is a lot more straight forwards, I'll put an example in the answer for you. (mysqli *API* is used mainly for programs that are not using user input and for queries that are absolute - you **shouldn't** have injections if you're not passing **un-trusted** data). Use the `bind parameter` in **PDO** if you're passing un-trusted data.

Comment: thx for another good hint bcs as you guessed my intention is not to create a web-shop (not interest in forms at all) so no user inputs.